# PHP - DOM extract part of anchor element

Tags: php, regex, dom

The first td  is not needed. If I loop can I enumerate the cells ? and then slect for example td[1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/) ?

```
// [Download simple_html_dom.php][1]
include "simple_html_dom.php";
$table = '<table>
 <tr bgcolor="#F3F3F3" height="22" style="height:25px">

// The first  td not needed          
<td width="20"></td>

// The second td need the node value. 
<td width="295" ><a href="/projecten/482039/N1.asp">a needed cell 1</a>      
</td>   

// The third td need the user from it.
<td width="90"><center><a href="?p=companyprofile&user=abcd" target="_blank"></a>   
</center></td>       



   //*******************************************************************************
   //and so on and so on till eod   

   <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="22" style="height:25px">
   <td width="20"></td>
   <td width="295" ><a class="d_link" href="/projecten/482320/xxx.asp">xxx</a></td>
   <td width="90"><center><a href="?p=companyprofile&user=yyyyy"         
    target="_blank"></a></center></td>    <td width="120" ><span     
    class="d_tekst">Brussel</span></td>    <td width="65" ><span 
    class="d_tekst">13:54</span></td>    <td width="120" ><font face="Verdana" </small>
    color="#808080"><small><small>0  &nbsp;(<font color="#008080">nieuw project</font>)     
    </small>        </font></td></tr>    

</table>';

$html = str_get_html($table);



header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=sample.csv');

$fp = fopen("php://output", "w");

foreach($html->find('tr') as $element)
{ 
    $td = array();

 //foreach( $element->find('td') as $row)  
 //there must be another way
 //I want to read them one bij one. 
 //Well the fields are put in the array.  


{
        $td [] = $row->plaintext;
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $td);
}


fclose($fp);
```

---

Question I need to extract tagnames and nodevalues and I need to keep them together.
So that the user in row 1 corresponds to the other fields in row one. For example the projects.

---

Comment: Some code will help give you the right answer.

Comment: Part Two (after your example), you need it php style or Javascript type? you print this "row" with php?

Comment: yes I print with php. I echo $tdrows. I post some extra code for clarification.

Comment: then you can use the string system to get a substring, starting after the & and the = and before the ", or example using the code from the answer, maybe it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this...

```
<?php
$html='<td><a href="?p=companyprofile&user=abcd" target="_blank"></a></td>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $tag) {
        parse_str($tag->getAttribute('href'));

}
echo $user; //"prints" abcd
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use jquery, http://jquery.com,to do that.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var userArray = new Array();
        $('a').each(function(){
             var href_text = $(this).attr('href');
             if( href_text.indexOf('user=')>=0 ){
                  var index_of_username = href_text.indexOf('user=') + 5;
                  var user_name = href_text.substring(index_of_username);
                  userArray.push(user_name);
             }
        });
        //console.log(userArray);
    });
```

Do whatever you want with your array. Remove comment on console.log for testing to see array output in debug mode.

Comment: Thanks. Why would you use jquery ?